# Customize UIPickerWheel Based on Today's Date

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview

My app adds a quote each time the app is opened on a different date.  So, you open today it shows Day 1 Quote, then if you open tomorrow, or in a week, it adds Day 2 Quote.  For various reasons, I am unable to use iCloud to ensure user's devices stay synced on the same day.  So, I want to add a settings where users can choose which day they are on.  What I was thinking of was populating the UIPickerWheel with all the days leading up to that day.  Why?  Well, the quotes come from an XML which I am building as I am going, so there may not be days available for December right now, so I don't want the user to pick Day 365 and have nothing happen.  So, on the 5th, I would like the UIPickerWheel to show Day 1, Day 2..., Day 5.  I can get the current day of the year using:

```
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSInteger dc = [currentCalendar  ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                  inUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit
                                                 forDate:today];
```

What I want to know is how to make the UIPickerWheel display all the numbers leading up to that, along with the word Day.  So each row says Day 1, leading up to the current date.  Any thoughts?

UPDATE:  Here is what I have so far.  In the viewWillAppear I comment on what I would like each row to look like.

Here is what I have so far:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSInteger dc = [currentCalendar  ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                               inUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit
                                              forDate:today];

    return dc;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [options objectAtIndex:row];
}
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [options objectAtIndex:row]];

   }

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.title = @"Settings";
    explain.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Papyrus" size:24];
    options = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   //here is where I'm not sure how to add one item for each day in the year it is.  For example, today is the 4th day of the year, so I would like the items in the array to be Day:1, Day:2, Day:3, Day:4.

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

}
```

Comment: But how would I get it to not only add one row but add a whole other string?

Comment: @OscarApeland here is what I have so far.

Comment: `NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.12345]];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:5.43210]];` With doubles as the current day